# Dropdown menu does not work well for text separator

Tags: joomla-3.4, templates, menu-item, css, submenu

I'm using this template, http://joomlatemplates.me/clean-and-simple/ for Joomla ver 3.4.5.
Everything works fine except the text separator menu item. As shown on the picture below, I used About Us Single Article menu item, while Products menu I used Text Separator menu item.
I played around with the css but it doesn't work. Any suggestion??

[image]

[image]

Below is the some part of the css code for the menu:

```
 /* Navigation */
 #navbar-wrap { padding: 0px; margin:0 0 10px 0;  border-top: 1px solid #dedede; border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede; }
 #navbar { position: relative; height: 55px;}
 #navbar.row { margin-bottom: 0 }
 #navigation { padding:0 10px;}
 #navigation .menu { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
 #navigation .menu .icon-angle-right { position: absolute; right: 10px; top:50%; margin-top: -6px; color: #aaa; font-size: 12px; }
 #navigation .menu > li { display: block; float: left; }
 #navigation .menu > li ul {}
 #navigation .menu ul { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 100%; margin: 10px 0 0 0; /*IE6 only*/ _margin: 0; nowhitespace: afterproperty; opacity: 0; transition: all .2s ease-in-out; visibility: hidden; z-index: 99; }
 #navigation .menu ul ul { left: 100%; top: 0; }
 #navigation .menu ul ul li { width: 100% }
 #navigation .menu li { position: relative; list-style: none; }
 #navigation .menu li:hover > ul { margin: 0; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
 #navigation .menu a { display: block; position: relative; }
 /* current item */
 #navigation .menu > li > a:hover, #navigation .menu > li.sfHover > a, #navigation .menu > .active > a, #navigation .active > a:hover, #navigation .active > a:hover { color: #E95846;}
 #navigation .menu > .active > a, #navigation li.active > a { font-weight: bold; color: #E95846  }
 #navigation .menu > li { margin-right: 20px; padding:0 10px; }
 #navigation .menu a { height: 55px; color: #606060; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; line-height: 55px; font-size:16px; }
 /*drop-down styles*/
 #navigation .menu ul { border-top: none; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd; min-width:200px;}
 #navigation .menu li:hover ul { margin-top: 0; }
 #navigation .menu ul ul.sub-menu { margin-top: -1px; margin-left: 1px; }
 #navigation .menu ul li { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd }
 #navigation .menu ul li:first-child { }
 #navigation .menu ul li:last-child { border: 0 }
 #navigation .menu ul li > a:hover { color: #E95846 }
 #navigation .menu ul a { display: block; height: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 12px 15px; text-transform: none; border: 0px; line-height: 1.7em; }
 #navigation .selector { display: none }
 #navigation ul.sub-menu .icon-angle-down:before {content:"\f105"!important;}
 #navigation ul.sub-menu a { font-size:12px;}
 #navigation i { text-align:right}
 #menu-icon {display: none;}
 #slide-wrap a:hover{ color:#fff}
```

I tried to hard code to fix it with this code

```
 .separator {
   display:inline-block;
   font-size:16px;
   padding-top:15px;
   }
```

It works fine but it wont have the arrow menu like the one About Us has and the submenu box will not be aligned the same as About Us submenu box...

Comment: Try using `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block;`. If not, could you please provide a link to your site so we can inspect the code as the demo site doesn't provide a separator menu item

Comment: I used hack way of solving it. I used extrenal URL instead and put http:# for URL field, although the user able to click, it doesnt go anywhere. But the arrow menu won't show. I guess it works only for single article menu item. Here is the page, http://ryts-instruments.co.th/

Comment: The down chevron indicates the menu item has children.  Not sure if this will work on an external url or not.  Should do but is highly template dependent.